# Batch Script : File Existence Based on User Prompt Location

Tags: batch-file

Step for only one time
First time when the user executes the Batch file - 'Test.bat' it should prompt the user for Directory path & move the path to a text file - Path.txt and proceed with next step :Nextcommand

Step for Everytime
When the User runs the same batch file - 'Test.bat' from Second time, it should check for the existence of the above file 'Path.txt' in the above user specified directory and if available then proceed to next step :Nextcommand else have to create the file as specified in the above step.

My Code

```
echo off
@echo off
IF EXIST "%FileLoc%\FileLocationPath.txt" GOTO :NextCommand
set loc= Enter File Location:
set /p FileLoc=%loc%
@echo %FileLoc%>>FileLocationPath.txt
GOTO :NextCommand
```

Comment: I have removed the unnecessary portion of your code, to keep it specific to your question body. Can you please revisit the question and tell us what specifically isn't working with that code snippet and what you've tried yourself in resolving the issue before posting it here. Before you do so, please note that you're checking for the existence of a file using a variable which doesn't exist yet. I'd suggest you look at resolving the methodology, as currently it isn't a code issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information to survive, you need to write it to a file (there are other possibilities, like Registry, but a file is the easiest solution)

```
@echo off
setlocal 
IF EXIST "FileLocationPath.txt" (
  <"FileLocationPath.txt" set /p FileLoc=
  goto :NextCommand
) 
set /p "FileLoc=Enter File Location: "
>"FileLocationPath.txt" echo %FileLoc%
:NextCommand
echo using %FileLoc%
```

If you ever need to reset the default, just delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you want.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
call :check
if defined FileLoc (
      echo %FileLoc%
      pause
    ) else (
      set /p "FileLoc=Enter File Location: "
      echo/>>"%0"
      echo set "FileLoc=!FileLoc!">>"%0"
)    
goto :eof
:check
```

It will check the existance of the variable, which at first will not exist, User will enter it, then once user entered the location, it will store that location as a variable below the `:check` label. Each time from now when the script is ran, the check label is called and the already set location is set.